# CSS jQuery tabs - disable or hide all but 'today' on page load

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I have some tabs that work fine and open on the tab corresponding to today - by day of the week. I want to put dynamic content in the 7 day divs but only want todays div to load when the page loads and not all 7 divs as it will slow the page. The content for the other 6 divs should only load when the tab is clicked on.

http://www.hostelcities.com/dev/tabbed_layout/jquerytabs/jquerytab0.1.php

I think that I need to disable the 6 non active divs until clicked on.

I'd appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update content of the `div` via ajax request on tab click:

```
$('.tabnavigation li a').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
  $.get('ajax/test.html', { day = id },  function(data) {
   $('#' + id).html(data);
  });
});
```

Something like this. I've used id's of elements from your page but I didn't have a chance to check it.